# CiviCRM loads its own copy of jquery. This interferes with WP plugins

Tags: wordpress, civievent, spam

I am running Civi on WordPress.  I was getting spam registrations.  I installed WP-SpamShield which worked great until someone tried to register for an event.  This fails saying that cookies and javascript need to be enabled. I backed off to just used SI Captcha Anti-Spam.  This work ok for a month or so but then the spam registrations started again.  The SpamShield support folks figured out that the problem is that Civi loads its own version of jQuery.  They say this is know to be a bad thing to do: https://pippinsplugins.com/why-loading-your-own-jquery-is-irresponsible/

Any one know why Civi does this or how to disable it?

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, the article that you linked to says why it's irresponsible to remove the default jQuery in WordPress. Are you sure that CiviCRM is doing that? My understanding (possibly incorrect) was that Civi just uses its own.

Do you have the console errors that SpamShield was throwing that proves that this is what the error is? This may be a namespacing issue.

Comment: The error that SpamSheild throws is: ERROR: Sorry, there was an error. Please be sure JavaScript and Cookies are enabled in your browser and try again.  After sending diagnostics to the support folks at SpamShield they have concluded that the problem is in differences in the JavaScript version used by WP vs the one used by CiviCRM.

Comment: JohnFF is right, CIvi does not remove WP's copy of jQuery or to the best of my knowledge do anything to interfere with it.

Comment: I think the issue is that SpamSheild relies on using one version of Jquery within the system and having a second different copy breaks how it works.

Comment: @MikeUbell Then it becomes a trickier issue. Civi is far larger than your average plugin, and there is a major case for it to maintain its own jQuery - particularly that it works on 3 different Content Management Systems. Guaranteeing the same version across all three would not be possible.

Why not politely suggest to the SpamShield team that they look at namespacing their jQuery a touch more precisely?

Answer (score 1):

I use Google ReCaptcha on our User Login and Contribution pages. Problem solved, No more Spam Registrations. It has been working for several months. Plus it is much simpler for the users to check *I am not a robot* then to do the pictures, letters, numbers mess.

Comment: I will try that and see if it works better than the other Captcha plug in. Thanks